# How to deselect the contents of a table cell when I move to it?

Tags: cocoa, osx-mavericks, nstableview

I am successfully using

```
[myTable editColumn:aColumn row:aRow withEvent:nil select:NO];
```

to move to a different table cell and start editing it.

The problem is that the text is always selected, irrespective of the `select:` parameter. If the user isn't careful the pre-existing text is lost on the next key press. No problem navigating cells with the mouse.

The table is view-based, the cells are populated with a vanilla NSTextField, the content is bound via an NSArrayController to a local array, not Core Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this your next statement:

```
[_window.firstResponder performSelector:@selector(moveRight:)];
```

`_window` is your controller's window or whatever. Use `moveLeft:` if you prefer.